# Why is React considered server side rendering technology compared to Angular?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, reactjs

I was learning about ReactJs and I found that when it's rendering aspect is compared to AngularJs - for some reasons it's called that ReactJs is server-side rendering technology.

I'm surprised to know this!

Look at the [question # 10 here](https://www.edureka.co/blog/interview-questions/react-interview-questions/) or this [Youtube tutorial link](https://youtu.be/-dS9pvGqlX8?t=966)

As far as I understand both AngularJs and ReactJs can render on both client & server-side.

I'm quite curious about what am I missing here?

Comment: "As far as I understand both AngularJs and ReactJs can render on both client & server-side" yep that's true. You can find examples on the websites of both products I believe, and in countless tutorials and other articles. No doubt you can find demos which prove it (or build them yourselves). The only lesson you can take from what you've seen in those links is "sometimes people talk nonsense".

Comment: Ugh, question #10 link dated from this year, but seems completely inaccurate. I believe your understanding to be more correct that page. React is also undoubtedly more than just a "View" in MVC.

Comment: @DrewReese I've answered it myself considering to help the fresh college graduates or new programmers. It will be easy for them too to get confused like me. My answer should help them clarify their doubts

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Update: I've decided to not delete this thread as this kind of non-sense can be experienced by others as well. Read the comments on question!

There is no difference in terms of rendering wrt the client or server-side. The ReactJs and AngularJs are both client-side and server-side technologies.